# Fetch Game with time of EST Timezone

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I have Game table, from which I want to fetch game which started in time between 11:00:00 to 14:00:00. But my start_in_time stored in database is in UTC. And I want to fetch games started time 11:00:00 EST and 14:00:00 EST.

```
Game.where("Time((start_in_time at time zone 'UTC') at time zone 'EST') between '11:00:00' and '14:00:00' ")
```

I have used **mysql** as database above query but in database I am getting syntax error. How to make this correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query worked for me.

```
GamePlay.where('TIME(start_in_time) between ? and ? ',((DateTime.parse("5:00:00").to_time.in_time_zone('Asia/Calcutta')).strftime("%H:%M:%S")),(DateTime.parse("14:00:00").to_time.in_time_zone('Asia/Calcutta')).strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the user time zone,

`@game.timezone = 'EST'`

```
Game.where('start_in_time > ? AND start_in_time < ?',((DateTime.parse("11am").to_time.in_time_zone('EST')).time.strftime("%I:%M %p")),(DateTime.parse("2pm").to_time.in_time_zone('EST')).time.strftime("%I:%M %p"))
```

Here is a sample query,

```
Game.where('start_in_time > ? AND start_in_time < ?',((DateTime.parse("11am").to_time.in_time_zone('EST')).time.strftime("%I:%M %p")),(DateTime.parse("2am").to_time.in_time_zone('EST')).time.strftime("%I:%M %p"))

Game Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `games`.* FROM `games` WHERE (start_in_time > '06:30 AM' AND start_in_time < '09:30 PM')
```

Comment: Currently query is for all day and not specific to particular day. Want games started between 11:00:00 to 14:00:00 of any day .

Comment: `Game.where('TIME(start_in_time) > ? AND TIME(start_in_time) < ?','1:00:00'.to_time.in_time_zone('EST'),'11:00:00'.to_time.in_time_zone('EST'))`, pls check this query once

Comment: check the results first ignoring the query

Comment: getting error SyntaxError: (irb):17: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input

Comment: `Game.where('start_in_time > ? AND start_in_time < ?',((DateTime.parse("11am").to_time.in_time_zone('EST')).strftime("%I:%m %p")),(DateTime.parse("2pm").to_time.in_time_zone('EST')).strftime("%I:%m %p"))`

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `str‌​ftime' for Sat, 22 Oct 2016 06:00:00 EST -05:00:Time
 Please try -> (DateTime.parse("11am").to_time.in_time_zone('EST') It throws error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126381/discussion-between-sravan-and-shefalee-chaudhary).

Comment: You should take `11am` and `2pm`, you have taken the time wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`Game.where("Time(DATE_ADD(start_in_time, INTERVAL 8 HOUR)) between '11:00:00' and '14:00:00'")`

Comment: Here EST is not fixed, It's dynamic. So, it can be any time zone . I an not use DATE_ADD.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid hassles with Daylight Savings time, it would probably be better to use
`CONVERT_TZ`().  See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-upgrades.html